# How to use OAuth Applciation token generated by Docusign Python client [ApiClient.request_jwt_application_token()]?

Tags: python, oauth, docusignapi

I am writing a back end rest application using python that creates envelopes from templates and returns the front end application the url to the created envelope to be displayed.

Using the [Python client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client), I am able to create a valid OAuth token using the following lines:

```py
api_client = ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi")

resp = api_client.request_jwt_application_token(
    client_id=client_id, # the integrator key
    oauth_host_name=auth_server, # 'account-d.docusign.com'
    private_key_bytes=private_key_file.read(), # private key temp file containing key in bytes
    expires_in=expiration # 3600
)
```

The call is successful, and returns the following:

```py
resp
{
    'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAi...81z9D5w',
    'data': None,
    'expires_in': '28800',
    'refresh_token': None,
    'scope': None,
    'token_type': 'Application'
}
```

And the proper Authorization headers are set in the client:

```
api_client.default_headers
{
    'X-DocuSign-SDK': 'Python', 
    'User-Agent': 'Swagger-Codegen/1.0.0/python', 
    'Authorization': 'Application eyJ0eXAi...81z9D5w'
}
```

However, whenever I try to make any call, I get the following response:

```
envelope_api = EnvelopeApi(api_client)
envelope_api.get_envelope(account_id, envelope_id) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
docusign_esign.client.api_exception.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '120', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '14ac...388', 'Date': 'Fri, 20 Dec 2019 17:47:43 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'})
HTTP response body: b'{"errorCode":"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"One or both of Username and Password are invalid. invalid_request"}'
```

Is there an additional step to utilize this Application token? The [Python JWT example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt) is severely out of date, and the Python client repository does not mention any required changes to use the new call

[Commit introducing new application token functionality](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/commit/87faedcc550b317a78865b0e22f4f16b81a19c8a)

Answer (score 1):

You're generating an *application* token which is only useful in specific circumstances like with use with Datafeeds. In general, you want to be generating a *user* token, which will include a UserId as one of the parameters.

To do so, you need the `api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow` method. An example of how to use that is available on GitHub: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt/blob/master/example_base.py

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there documentation or examples where you would use an Application OAuth token over a User token?