# DocuSign Consent Required error with OAuth application token

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am trying to create a valid OAuth token using the following code:

```
def get_token():

    DS_JWT = {
        "ds_client_id": "79b1adb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4450dd98a712",
        "ds_impersonated_user_id": "3300d1d8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-552b87311b0f",
        "private_key_file": "private.key",
        "authorization_server": "account-d.docusign.com"
    }

    private_key = get_private_key(DS_JWT["private_key_file"]).encode("ascii").decode("utf-8")
    api_client = ApiClient()
    ds_app = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
        client_id=DS_JWT["ds_client_id"],
        user_id=DS_JWT["ds_impersonated_user_id"],
        oauth_host_name=DS_JWT["authorization_server"],
        private_key_bytes=private_key,
        expires_in=3600,
        scopes=["signature", "impersonation"]
    )

    return ds_app.access_token
```

I thought this would work, since other people use it ([How to use OAuth Applciation token generated by Docusign Python client [ApiClient.request_jwt_application_token()]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429819/how-to-use-oauth-applciation-token-generated-by-docusign-python-client-apiclien)).

But I get the following error:

````
  File "src/docusign_template_app/obtain_token_4.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "src/docusign_template_app/obtain_token_4.py", line 33, in main
    token_4 = get_token_4()
  File "src/docusign_template_app/obtain_token_4.py", line 18, in get_token_4
    ds_app = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py", line 691, in request_jwt_user_token
    response = self.request("POST", "https://" + oauth_host_name + "/oauth/token",
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py", line 393, in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_response.py", line 246, in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_response.py", line 208, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
docusign_esign.client.api_exception.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
Trace-Token: eadcd891-a820-414c-a86e-3a51f318361c
Timestamp: Tue, 30 Aug 2022 09:17:05 GMT
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'expires': '-1', 'x-docusign-tracetoken': 'eadcd891-a820-414c-a8
6e-3a51f318361c', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block; report=/client-errors/xss', 'x-docusign-node': 'DA1DFE179', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer,strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'date': 'Tue, 30 Aug 2022 09:17:05 GMT', 'content-length': '28'})
HTTP response body: b'{"error":"consent_required"}'```
````

Comment: ***Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Because you're including the user id, you're actually obtaining a user access token, not an application access token.

### Good news

Your software is correct. The error message you received is `consent required.` This error indicates that:

1. Your request is correctly made
2. But the user has not yet granted consent for your application to impersonate them.

To fix the problem, see the options documented in my [Granting Consent](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent) blog post.

Ask a **new** question on StackOverflow if you have any related questions.

Comment: Hi, to get an application access token what do we need instead of the user id?

Comment: Application credentials do not work with the DocuSign e-signature API, only with some of the other DocuSign APIs including the admin API